# How can I get value in doPost?

Tags: unit-test, rest, code-coverage

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/MilestoneRESTHandler/*')
global with sharing  class KLMilestoneRestResource 
{
    @HttpPost
    global static ResponseWrapper  doPost()
    {
        string jsonStr;
        if (RestContext.request.requestBody<>null) 
        {
            jsonStr= RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
        }

        string plantcode;
        map<integer,string> mpSequencetoMilestoneID = new map<integer,string>();
        ResponseWrapper objresponse = new ResponseWrapper();
        try{ 
            KLMilestoneJSON objMilestoneWrapper = KLMilestoneJSON.parse(jsonStr);

            list<KL_Milestone__c> lstToUpsertMilestone = new list<KL_Milestone__c>();


            Schema.SObjectField ExternalField = KL_Milestone__c.Fields.KL_Milestone_Code__c;
            system.debug('objMilestoneWrapper::'+objMilestoneWrapper.Record);
            integer i=0;
            boolean hasError = false; 

            for(KLMilestoneJSON.Record objRecord: objMilestoneWrapper.Record )
            {

                KL_Milestone__c objMilestone = new  KL_Milestone__c();
                if(objRecord.KL_Milestone_Code !=null && objRecord.KL_Milestone_Code !=''  )
                {
                    objMilestone.KL_Milestone_Code__c = objRecord.KL_Milestone_Code;
                    mpSequencetoMilestoneID.put(i++,objRecord.KL_Milestone_Code );
                }
                else
                {
                    hasError=true;
                }
                if(objRecord.KL_Plant_UID != null && objRecord.KL_Plant_UID != '' )
                {
                    objMilestone.KL_Plant_UID__c= objRecord.KL_Plant_UID;
                    plantcode = objRecord.KL_Plant_UID;
                }
                else
                {
                    hasError=true;
                }

                if(objRecord.KL_Network_Number != null && objRecord.KL_Network_Number != '' )
                {
                    objMilestone.KL_Network_Number__c =objRecord.KL_Network_Number;

                }
                else
                {
                    hasError=true;

                }
                if(objRecord.KL_Usage != null && objRecord.KL_Usage != '' )
                {   
                    objMilestone.KL_Usage__c = objRecord.KL_Usage;

                }
                else
                {
                    hasError=true;
                }

                objMilestone.KL_Description__c = objRecord.KL_Description;
                if(objRecord.KL_Scheduled_Completion_Date != '' && objRecord.KL_Scheduled_Completion_Date != null )
                {
                        objMilestone.KL_Scheduled_Completion_Date__c    = Date.parse(objRecord.KL_Scheduled_Completion_Date);
                }

                if(objRecord.KL_Actual_Completion_Date != '' && objRecord.KL_Actual_Completion_Date != null  
                        && !objRecord.KL_Actual_Completion_Date.equalsIgnoreCase('null'))
                {
                        objMilestone.KL_Actual_Completion_Date__c =  Date.parse(objRecord.KL_Actual_Completion_Date);
                }

                if(objRecord.KL_Milestone_Percent != null  &&  objRecord.KL_Milestone_Percent != '')
                {   
                    objMilestone.KL_Milestone_Percent__c =  Decimal.valueof(objRecord.KL_Milestone_Percent.trim());
                }
                else
                {
                    hasError=true;
                }
                lstToUpsertMilestone.add(objMilestone);
            }
            if(hasError)
            {
                objresponse.Records.add(new Record('Error','','Required fields are missing.' ,'',plantcode));

                return objresponse;
            }


            if(lstToUpsertMilestone != null && lstToUpsertMilestone.size()>0)
            {   
                upsert lstToUpsertMilestone KL_Milestone_Code__c;
                objresponse.Records.add(new Record('Success','','Milestones created or updated successfully.','',plantcode));
            }
            system.debug(objresponse);

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {       
            //throw new KLMilestoneRestResource.ThroughException(ex.getMessage());
            KL_Error_Log__c errorLog = KLCommon.createErrorLog('MILESTONE INBOUND',null,'KLMilestoneRestResource','doPost','Insert'
            ,null,'Milestone','',jsonStr,ex.getMessage() );
            errorLog.KL_Error_catagory__c='Inbound';
            insert errorLog;

            objresponse.Records.add(new Record('Error','',ex.getMessage(),'',plantcode));
        }
        return objresponse;

    }

    global class ResponseWrapper
    {
        public list<Record> Records;

        public ResponseWrapper()
        {
            Records = new list<Record>();           
        }

    }

    class Record 
    {
        public String ZTYPE;
        public String ZNUMBER;
        public String ZMESSAGE;
        public String ZID ;
        public String ZREF_NO; 
        public Record(String ZTYPE , String ZNUMBER, String ZMESSAGE, String ZID,String ZREF_NO)
        {
            this.ZTYPE= ZTYPE;
            this.ZNUMBER= ZNUMBER;
            this.ZMESSAGE= ZMESSAGE;
            this.ZID= ZID;
            this.ZREF_NO= ZREF_NO;
        } 
    }

    private class ThroughException extends Exception {}

}
```

Comment: I have created a milestone Record and trying this KLMilestoneRestResource.ResponseWrapper obj1= new KLMilestoneRestResource.ResponseWrapper();
  //obj1.Records = lstMilestone;

Comment: Add the Test Class and Mock class that you created for unit test.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the static `RestContext.request` variable. It is writeable.

```
static testMethod void testApexRest()
{
    RestContext.request = new RestRequest();
    RestContext.request.requestBody = Blob.valueOf('"JSON_payload"');

    Test.startTest();
        MyRestClass.myRestMethod();
    Test.stopTest();

    // assertions
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to build a mock for your test. Please, follow this instructions on how to test HTTP Callout: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm

Comment: This is not an HTTP Callout. This is a Custom Apex REST Resource. A mock Class is not required for testing. The REST Resource can be tested just like any other Apex Class.